# Cascading for custom form JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices

I have a custom form in SharePoint online which I have created using HTML, it has two drop down columns in which I am populating data from a list where for example I have columns, `Country` & `States`.  Thease dropdowns are populated using rest api from the list which has both country and state column.

```
 $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "ListName",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "States",
    parentColumn: "Country Category",
    childColumn: "State Title",
    debug: true
  });
```

But this code doesn't seem to work. Is this code only for sharepoint list forms, does it also work for custom forms?

Answer (score 2):

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "StatesListName",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "States",
    parentColumn: "CountryCategory", //Internal name of the column
    childColumn: "StateTitle", //Internal name of the column
    debug: true
  });
```

Comment: It is a custom column, what would be the internal name for it
`<select id="SID"> <option  value="">Select</option>`

Comment: Go to the list setting page and click on the column. On edit column page, you will find the "Field" query string in the URL of this page. The value of this field is the internal name of the column.

Comment: I know this, but the columns that I have created is not coming  from the list, Its just a html textbox

Comment: SPServices Cascading is used with the SharePoint lists which share a lookup relationship among themselves. You can't use a textbox.